# Using google map into excel

Tags: string, vba, excel

This is my first question so I am re-editing to better suit the culture here in stack overflow!
I recently found the API below that helps me plan out my trips/stops for a wide range of activities. It gives me the distance, directions, and time on excel! I have a wide variety of address that I use and I need the data of each in an excel format.

Problem: I have a problem where I want to find out my time/duration to get to a certain location to the next based on the time and day. For example if i want to depart toronto at 4:00pm to get to chicago, how long will that take based on the average traffic records.

This is pretty relevant to others who are in need of geocoding information on their excel! I am not very familiar with programming,vba, and sql but i definitely want to get into it so this is a good stepping stone to learn some cool stuff!

```
' Usage :
' GetGoogleTravelTime (strFrom, strTo) returns a string containing journey duration : hh:mm
' GetGoogleDistance (strFrom, strTo) returns a string containing journey distance in either miles or km (as defined by strUnits)
' GetGoogleDirections (strFrom, strTo) returns a string containing the directions
'
' where strFrom/To are address search terms recognisable by Google
' i.e. Postcode, address etc.
'
'
Const strUnits = "imperial" ' imperial/metric (miles/km)

Function CleanHTML(ByVal strHTML)
'Helper function to clean HTML instructions
Dim strInstrArr1() As String
Dim strInstrArr2() As String
Dim s As Integer

strInstrArr1 = Split(strHTML, "<")
For s = LBound(strInstrArr1) To UBound(strInstrArr1)
   strInstrArr2 = Split(strInstrArr1(s), ">")
   If UBound(strInstrArr2) > 0 Then
        strInstrArr1(s) = strInstrArr2(1)
   Else
        strInstrArr1(s) = strInstrArr2(0)
   End If
Next

CleanHTML = Join(strInstrArr1)
End Function

Public Function formatGoogleTime(ByVal lngSeconds As Double)
'Helper function. Google returns the time in seconds, so this converts it into time format hh:mm

Dim lngMinutes As Long
Dim lngHours As Long

lngMinutes = Fix(lngSeconds / 60)
lngHours = Fix(lngMinutes / 60)
lngMinutes = lngMinutes - (lngHours * 60)

formatGoogleTime = Format(lngHours, "00") & ":" & Format(lngMinutes, "00")
End Function




Function gglDirectionsResponse(ByVal strStartLocation, ByVal strEndLocation, ByRef strTravelTime, ByRef strDistance, ByRef strInstructions, Optional ByRef strError = "") As Boolean
On Error GoTo errorHandler
' Helper function to request and process XML generated by Google Maps.

Dim strURL As String
Dim objXMLHttp As Object
Dim objDOMDocument As Object
Dim nodeRoute As Object
Dim lngDistance As Long

Set objXMLHttp = CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")
Set objDOMDocument = CreateObject("MSXML2.DOMDocument.6.0")

strStartLocation = Replace(strStartLocation, " ", "+")
strEndLocation = Replace(strEndLocation, " ", "+")

strURL = "http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/xml" & _
            "?origin=" & strStartLocation & _
            "&destination=" & strEndLocation & _
            "&sensor=false" & _
            "&units=" & strUnits   'Sensor field is required by google and indicates whether a Geo-sensor is being used by the device making the request

'Send XML request
With objXMLHttp
    .Open "GET", strURL, False
    .setRequestHeader "Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-URLEncoded"
    .Send
    objDOMDocument.LoadXML .ResponseText
End With

With objDOMDocument
    If .SelectSingleNode("//status").Text = "OK" Then
        'Get Distance
        lngDistance = .SelectSingleNode("/DirectionsResponse/route/leg/distance/value").Text ' Retrieves distance in meters
        Select Case strUnits
            Case "imperial": strDistance = Round(lngDistance * 0.00062137, 1)  'Convert meters to miles
            Case "metric": strDistance = Round(lngDistance / 1000, 1) 'Convert meters to miles
        End Select

        'Get Travel Time
        strTravelTime = .SelectSingleNode("/DirectionsResponse/route/leg/duration/value").Text  'returns in seconds from google
        strTravelTime = formatGoogleTime(strTravelTime) 'converts seconds to hh:mm

        'Get Directions
        For Each nodeRoute In .SelectSingleNode("//route/leg").ChildNodes
            If nodeRoute.BaseName = "step" Then
                strInstructions = strInstructions & nodeRoute.SelectSingleNode("html_instructions").Text & " - " & nodeRoute.SelectSingleNode("distance/text").Text & vbCrLf
            End If
        Next

        strInstructions = CleanHTML(strInstructions) 'Removes MetaTag information from HTML result to convert to plain text.

    Else
        strError = .SelectSingleNode("//status").Text
        GoTo errorHandler
    End If
End With

gglDirectionsResponse = True
GoTo CleanExit

errorHandler:
    If strError = "" Then strError = Err.Description
    strDistance = -1
    strTravelTime = "00:00"
    strInstructions = ""
    gglDirectionsResponse = False

CleanExit:
    Set objDOMDocument = Nothing
    Set objXMLHttp = Nothing

End Function


Function getGoogleTravelTime(ByVal strFrom, ByVal strTo) As String
'Returns the journey time between strFrom and strTo

Dim strTravelTime As String
Dim strDistance As String
Dim strInstructions As String
Dim strError As String

If gglDirectionsResponse(strFrom, strTo, strTravelTime, strDistance, strInstructions, strError) Then
    getGoogleTravelTime = strTravelTime
Else
    getGoogleTravelTime = strError
End If

End Function

Function getGoogleDistance(ByVal strFrom, ByVal strTo) As String
'Returns the distance between strFrom and strTo
'where strFrom/To are address search terms recognisable by Google
'i.e. Postcode, address etc.

Dim strTravelTime As String
Dim strDistance As String
Dim strError As String
Dim strInstructions As String

If gglDirectionsResponse(strFrom, strTo, strTravelTime, strDistance, strInstructions, strError) Then
    getGoogleDistance = strDistance
Else
    getGoogleDistance = strError
End If

End Function

Function getGoogleDirections(ByVal strFrom, ByVal strTo) As String
'Returns the directions between strFrom and strTo
'where strFrom/To are address search terms recognisable by Google
'i.e. Postcode, address etc.

Dim strTravelTime As String
Dim strDistance As String
Dim strError As String
Dim strInstructions As String

If gglDirectionsResponse(strFrom, strTo, strTravelTime, strDistance, strInstructions, strError) Then
    getGoogleDirections = strInstructions
Else
    getGoogleDirections = strError
End If

End Function
```

Anything would help.

Comment: *if any of you know how to see if we can implement* - what have *you* tried to do to implement this and what's not working? that is something we can help with.

Comment: Why people are not forced to take the tutorial and read  [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) before write the first question?

Comment: I re-edit based on some of the asking tips. I hope it helps! Let me know if there is an issue. Thank you stack team!

Answer (score 0):

I hope it helps.

This works by using an API so that you are able to get Google map's information through those functions.

```
' Usage :
' GetGoogleTravelTime (strFrom, strTo) returns a string containing journey duration : hh:mm
' GetGoogleDistance (strFrom, strTo) returns a string containing journey distance in either miles or km (as defined by strUnits)
' GetGoogleDirections (strFrom, strTo) returns a string containing the directions
'
' where strFrom/To are address search terms recognisable by Google
' i.e. Postcode, address etc.
'
' by Desmond Oshiwambo

Const strUnits = "imperial" ' imperial/metric (miles/km)

Function CleanHTML(ByVal strHTML)
'Helper function to clean HTML instructions
Dim strInstrArr1() As String
Dim strInstrArr2() As String
Dim s As Integer

strInstrArr1 = Split(strHTML, "<")
For s = LBound(strInstrArr1) To UBound(strInstrArr1)
 strInstrArr2 = Split(strInstrArr1(s), ">")
   If UBound(strInstrArr2) > 0 Then
        strInstrArr1(s) = strInstrArr2(1)
   Else
        strInstrArr1(s) = strInstrArr2(0)
   End If
Next

CleanHTML = Join(strInstrArr1)
End Function


Public Function formatGoogleTime(ByVal lngSeconds As Double)
'Helper function. Google returns the time in seconds, so this converts it into time format hh:mm

Dim lngMinutes As Long
Dim lngHours As Long

lngMinutes = Fix(lngSeconds / 60)
lngHours = Fix(lngMinutes / 60)
lngMinutes = lngMinutes - (lngHours * 60)

formatGoogleTime = Format(lngHours, "00") & ":" & Format(lngMinutes, "00")
End Function


Function gglDirectionsResponse(ByVal strStartLocation, ByVal strEndLocation, ByRef strTravelTime, ByRef strDistance, ByRef strInstructions, Optional ByRef strError = "") As Boolean
On Error GoTo errorHandler
' Helper function to request and process XML generated by Google Maps.

Dim strURL As String
Dim objXMLHttp As Object
Dim objDOMDocument As Object
Dim nodeRoute As Object
Dim lngDistance As Long

Set objXMLHttp = CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")
Set objDOMDocument = CreateObject("MSXML2.DOMDocument.6.0")

strStartLocation = Replace(strStartLocation, " ", "+")
strEndLocation = Replace(strEndLocation, " ", "+")

strURL = "http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/xml" & _
            "?origin=" & strStartLocation & _
            "&destination=" & strEndLocation & _
            "&sensor=false" & _
            "&units=" & strUnits   'Sensor field is required by google and indicates whether a Geo-sensor is being used by the device making the request

'Send XML request
With objXMLHttp
    .Open "GET", strURL, False
    .setRequestHeader "Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-URLEncoded"
    .send
    objDOMDocument.LoadXML .responseText
End With

With objDOMDocument
    If .SelectSingleNode("//status").Text = "OK" Then
        'Get Distance
        lngDistance = .SelectSingleNode("/DirectionsResponse/route/leg/distance/value").Text ' Retrieves distance in meters
        Select Case strUnits
            Case "imperial": strDistance = Round(lngDistance * 0.00062137, 1)  'Convert meters to miles
            Case "metric": strDistance = Round(lngDistance / 1000, 1) 'Convert meters to miles
        End Select

        'Get Travel Time
        strTravelTime = .SelectSingleNode("/DirectionsResponse/route/leg/duration/value").Text  'returns in seconds from google
        strTravelTime = formatGoogleTime(strTravelTime) 'converts seconds to hh:mm

        'Get Directions
        For Each nodeRoute In .SelectSingleNode("//route/leg").ChildNodes
            If nodeRoute.BaseName = "step" Then
                strInstructions = strInstructions & nodeRoute.SelectSingleNode("html_instructions").Text & " - " & nodeRoute.SelectSingleNode("distance/text").Text & vbCrLf
            End If
        Next

        strInstructions = CleanHTML(strInstructions) 'Removes MetaTag information from HTML result to convert to plain text.

    Else
        strError = .SelectSingleNode("//status").Text
        GoTo errorHandler
    End If
End With

gglDirectionsResponse = True
GoTo CleanExit

errorHandler:
    If strError = "" Then strError = Err.Description
    strDistance = -1
    strTravelTime = "00:00"
    strInstructions = ""
    gglDirectionsResponse = False

CleanExit:
    Set objDOMDocument = Nothing
    Set objXMLHttp = Nothing

End Function


Function getGoogleTravelTime(ByVal strFrom, ByVal strTo) As String
'Returns the journey time between strFrom and strTo

Dim strTravelTime As String
Dim strDistance As String
Dim strInstructions As String
Dim strError As String

If gglDirectionsResponse(strFrom, strTo, strTravelTime, strDistance, strInstructions, strError) Then
    getGoogleTravelTime = strTravelTime
Else
    getGoogleTravelTime = strError
End If

End Function


Function getGoogleDistance(ByVal strFrom, ByVal strTo) As String
'Returns the distance between strFrom and strTo
'where strFrom/To are address search terms recognisable by Google
'i.e. Postcode, address etc.

Dim strTravelTime As String
Dim strDistance As String
Dim strError As String
Dim strInstructions As String

If gglDirectionsResponse(strFrom, strTo, strTravelTime, strDistance, strInstructions, strError) Then
    getGoogleDistance = strDistance
Else
    getGoogleDistance = strError
End If

End Function


Function getGoogleDirections(ByVal strFrom, ByVal strTo) As String
'Returns the directions between strFrom and strTo
'where strFrom/To are address search terms recognisable by Google
'i.e. Postcode, address etc.

Dim strTravelTime As String
Dim strDistance As String
Dim strError As String
Dim strInstructions As String

If gglDirectionsResponse(strFrom, strTo, strTravelTime, strDistance, strInstructions, strError) Then
    getGoogleDirections = strInstructions
Else
    getGoogleDirections = strError
End If

End Function
Public Function ACOF(Rango As Range) As Variant
 Dim x(), y(), z() As Variant
 Dim i, n, mu, k, j As Double
  n = Rango.Rows.Count
  mu = Application.Average(Rango)
  k = 1
  ReDim z(n - k)
 Do Until k = n - 1
 ReDim x(n - k), y(n - k)
   For i = 1 To n - k Step 1
    x(i) = Rango(i) - mu
    y(i) = Rango(i + k) - mu
   Next i
z(k) = Application.Correl(x, y) 'Application.SumProduct(x, y) / Application.DevSq(Rango)
 k = k + 1
Loop
ACOF = Application.Transpose(z)
End Function

Public Function JBTEST(Rango As Range, p As Double) As Variant
 If IsNull(Rango) Then
  MsgBox prompt:="Introduce un rango válido"
   End If
 Dim s, k, n As Double
  s = Application.Skew(Rango)
  k = Application.Kurt(Rango)
  n = Rango.Rows.Count
   JBTEST = Application.ChiDist((n - p + 1) / 6 * (s ^ 2 + 1 / 4 * (k - 3) ^ 2), 2)

End Function

Function IFERROR(ByRef ToEvaluate As Variant, ByRef Default As Variant) As Variant
    If IsError(ToEvaluate) Then
        IFERROR = Default
    Else
        IFERROR = ToEvaluate
    End If
End Function

Sub RegisterUDF()
    Dim s As String
    s = "Provides a shortcut replacement for the common worksheet construct" & vbLf _
    & "IF(ISERROR(<expression>, <default>, <expression>)"

    Application.MacroOptions Macro:="IFERROR", Description:=s, Category:=9
End Sub

Sub UnregisterUDF()
    Application.MacroOptions Macro:="IFERROR", Description:=Empty, Category:=Empty
End Sub
```